# How to rewrite this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

Here is my table:

```
drop table if exists daily_scores;
create table daily_scores (
  day date,
  score int
);
```

It contains the following data:

```
insert into daily_scores(day, score) values('2016-01-01', 1);
insert into daily_scores(day, score) values('2016-01-02', 2);
insert into daily_scores(day, score) values('2016-01-03', 3);
insert into daily_scores(day, score) values('2016-01-04', 10);
```

I want to generate a weekly report as it would be seen each day.
So on the 1st of Jan, I would have 1, on the 2nd 3, the 3rd 6 etc

To produce the expected results, I ran the query below:

```
select days.day,sum(score)
from daily_scores ds
inner join (select day from daily_scores) days on 1=1
where ds.day <= days.day
group by days.day
order by days.day
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+------------+----+
|    day     |sum |
+------------+----+
| 2016-01-01 |  1 |
+------------+----+
| 2016-01-02 |  3 |
+------------+----+
| 2016-01-03 |  6 |
+------------+----+
| 2016-01-04 | 16 |
+------------+----+
```

Is it possible to write this query differently?

**Postgresql 9.5**

Comment: Just a side note: You inner join a query (`select day from daily_scores`) with no where clause, so you could just as well join the table directly. Then, you *inner* join this, but use `1=1` as criteria, which would rather be a *cross* join, so why do you call it inner join with the need for a dummy ON clause? And then in your where clause there suddenly *is* the criteria to link the subquery to the table, so at last it is again an inner join. Next time just write `inner join daily_scores days on ds.day <= days.day`.

Comment: Another point is that you should have a qualifier to sum `ds.scores`. It seems you were lucky and the DBMS chose that `scores` field, but it could just as well have chosen `days.scores` instead. (Or what I would have liked best: thrown an ambiguity exception.) Then it seems strange that it is the joined table that you use as base; it should be just the other way round for readability.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner In my real life case, I need the inner join like this. Sorry, if the simplification process for this question doesn't reflect this need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sum` window function to get the cumulative sum.

```
select day,sum(score) over(order by day) cumulative_sum
from daily_scores
```

Answer (score 1):

If postgres supports windowed aggregate functions

```
Select day,sum(score) Over(Order by day ASC) as sum 
From yourtable
```

Another approach (Not sure about performance)

```
Select day,(select sum(score) from yourtable b where b.day <= a.day) as sum 
From yourtable a
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like to use the specific postgres syntax you can use a normal inner join as follow:

```
select ds.day, sum(ds2.score)
from daily_scores ds
inner join daily_scores ds2 on
ds2.day <= ds.day
group by ds.day
```